# Why are not you passing the parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Parameters are not being passed to the model, so the sql query is not yielding results. It just shows nothing, not even errors. Why are not the parameters being passed to the model?The sql query in the database works correctly, the date before the variables is to ignore the time, since in the database the field is of type datetime

Controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('M_Login');
     $this->load->model('M_Porcentaje');


}

public function tabla_porcentaje(){


$fecha_ini = $this->input->post('fecha_ini');
$fecha_ter = $this->input->post('fecha_ter');



$data['consulta'] = $this->M_Porcentaje->tabla_porcentaje($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter);
$this->load->view('usuarios/test.php',$data);


 }
```

Model

```
public function tabla_porcentaje ($fecha_ini, $fecha_ter){



$this->db->select("motivos_citas.descripcion_mot,COUNT(*) AS cantidad_motivos, (SELECT COUNT(motivos_citas.descripcion_mot)* 100 / COUNT(citas.id_ci) FROM citas AS citas WHERE date(citas.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$fecha_ini') AND date('$fecha_ter') ) AS porcentaje");
$this->db->from("citas");
$this->db->join("motivos_citas","citas.id_mot=motivos_citas.id_mot");
$this->db->where("date(citas.fecha_ini) BETWEEN date('$fecha_ini') AND date('$fecha_ter') ");
$this->db->group_by("motivos_citas.descripcion_mot");
$consulta = $this->db->get();

 return $consulta->result();
}
```

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn_buscar").click(function(evento){


 var fecha_ini =  $("#fecha_ini").val();
 var fecha_ter =  $("#fecha_ter").val();

 $.ajax({

  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje/",
  type: 'post',
  data: { "fecha_ini": fecha_ini, "fecha_ter": fecha_ter },

    success: function(response){ 

       alert($("#fecha_ini").val());
       alert($("#fecha_ter").val());
       window.open('<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje/', '_blank');
     }

    });

   });

  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Is the success handler being called?

Comment: Look at your developer console in your browser too for any errors it may be spitting out. If it has them, please add to your post.

Comment: success  not called

Comment: I guess it's because they are not passing the data, although I do not see the error in the code

Comment: is the click handler called when you click on `#buscar` element?

Comment: It does not call the controller, however if I remove the parameters and success, if it calls, so I'm not passing the data, but I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is not okay. You should use :

> $(document).on('click', '#buscar',function(url){

Comment: That does not work, just add $ (document) .on (function () {ETC, I do not know if you mean that

Comment: You should alert something right after the on click event and see if it triggers.

Comment: Yes, it should show an error or something, but it does not   :C

Comment: Is the ajax executing? Can you see it in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))` rather than `$this->input->post()` if the controller will read the data.

```
public function tabla_porcentaje(){

  $input_post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $data = array (
   'fecha_ini' => $input_post->fecha_ini,
   'fecha_ter' => $input_post->fecha_ter
  );

   $this->load->model('M_Porcentaje_PDF');
   $this->M_Porcentaje_PDF->tabla_porcentaje($data);

}
```